# Apache Beam / GCP Datawflow: read video/image files

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, video-processing, apache-beam

I am struggling to understand how to create a pipeline which involves reading and manipulating a video/image file.
Looking into the documentation, which is quite "essential" without examples and few comments, maybe the beam.io package should help, i.e. class LocalFileSystem

However I have no idea how to use it to create a working pipeline which reads and apply some transform (i.e. frame extraction with ffmpeg)

I am using using python, however if java is more documented i can switch.

Any example? any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably need to write a subclass of `FileBasedSource` with `splitable=False` and implement your own `read_records`. https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py#L201

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you can specifying `ffmpeg` in the workers in order to use it for image/video processing. To upload the specified resources instead of default ones to the workers, use `filesToStage` [pipeline option](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-pipeline-options). To use this option, you should use Java SDK since it is not available in Python.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321113/can-google-cloud-dataflow-apache-beam-use-ffmpeg-to-process-video-or-image-dat) for more details about use `ffmpeg` in pipeline and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621488/does-it-make-sense-to-use-google-dataflow-apache-beam-to-parallelize-image-proce) to have a overview about the process.